# Use PHPExcel to store spreadsheets in a MySQL table and display said table on a PHP page with the spreadsheets in the generated tables

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

Is it possible to use PHPExcel to do something like this.

PHP page:

```
Document Name        Date Submitted        Some Other Column Name
spreadsheet.xls(x)   2012-01-01            yada yada yada
spreadsheet2.xls(x)  2002-12-12            blah blah blah
```

The MySQL table will more or less look like the above.

Then the document name will contain a link so that once clicked, it opens the spreadsheet in the browser, and then the user can edit and so on, and when the user's done, the Excel file is updated.

Is this in any way possible?

Comment: you want functionality like google doc?

Comment: You would need to write a GUI to allow this: PHPExcel is a PHP library for reading/writing/modifying spreadsheet files from within PHP scripts; it isn't an interactive, front-end editor... it's possible (I once did it) but it's a lot of work writing your own GUI, and I also used a specialised daemon process that kept the file open on the server while the file was being edited

Comment: @YogeshSuthar yes something like Google doc. I'm trying to get some kids interested in programming and this was one of the ideas one of the bright kids came up with

Comment: @MarkBaker how were you able to accomplish that? Can you help?

Comment: If you want to get kids interested in programming, then this is a non-trivial task... the basis of the GUI was a customised version of the HTML Writer that (for example) defined ID and name elements for every cell, and stored both the cell value in a hidden field together with the displayed formatted value; and with a whole load of javascript to handle editing cells, right click to provide style settings, etc. Every change to a cell triggered and ajax call to the server side process, which recalculated all the cells in the displayed range and sent that back to the GUI for display

Comment: On the server, I had a daemon controller process running in the background that forked off a thread for every workbook opened by the front-end, assigning it an ID that was stored in session: the apache/PHP request communicated directly with the daemon, using the value ID from session to indicate the spreadsheet being updated... the daemon identified the forked thread to work with from that ID value, to send the update requests; the thread handled the update to the PHPExcel object in memory and returned its response to the controller, which formatted it and returned it as the Ajax response.

Comment: Performance was just about adequate running in a small restricted network, better when all run on localhost... I only did it as a Proof Of Concept though, it was never intended as a product, and certainly wouldn't have been fit for that purpose. It took several months to get it working correctly, and needed a whole host of technologies (threading and socket communications, Ajax, etc) as well as js and PHP coding, and a good knowlegde of the Excel format and the PHPExcel library

Comment: That sounds like a lot of work. But well, how do I get started?

Comment: It is a lot of work: If I were to do it again, I'd start with the writer and the javascript, to ensure that I could generate a GUI page where data could be edited.